# i get an uppercased table name calling a variable

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, uppercase, mysql-variables

I set a variable name for a table as lowercase:

```
Set TGT_TABLE = 'tab_name';
```

however when i try to call it:

```
select * from table($TGT_TABLE);
```

I get an error:

```
SQL compilation error: Object 'TAB_NAME' does not exist or not authorized.
```

Why is it calling the uppercase version of my table name
Also I veriefied in the 'show variables' that my variable is indeed lowercase

Comment: Is the table created as tab_name or TAB_NAME?

Comment: in lowercase : tab_name

Comment: I'd test `Set TGT_TABLE = '"tab_name"'`, to keep casing. (Or perhaps back-ticks instead of double quotes.)

Comment: this is solving the problem
i tried :
Set TGT_TABLE = "tab_name"; but i got the eroor : not working /  invalid identifier
thanks a lot :)

Comment: Is this for Snowflake or MySQL? You have both tags.

Comment: it is for snowflake, i couldn't add the tag snowflake-variables !

Answer (score 2):

You can Write Your Code Like This :

```
declare @TGT_TABLE nvarchar(50),@query nvarchar(50)

Set @TGT_TABLE = 'name of your table';

SET @query = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @TGT_TABLE;
     
EXEC(@query);
```

It will worked.

Answer (score 2):

in order to use lower case identifiers, these must be in double-quotes. in order to assign it to a variable, this must additionally be in single quotes.

@jarlh 's answer is correct, note the single quotes surrounding the double quotes.

```
Set TGT_TABLE = '"tab_name"';
select * from table($TGT_TABLE);
```

if in doubt, copy/ paste